# Trying to subclass CCMenuItemImage

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

Im subclassing CCMenuItemImage with this init method

```
-(id)initWithChildren:(id)targetedApplication {
    if(self = [super initFromNormalImage:@"Answer_Box.png" selectedImage:@"Answer_Box.png" disabledImage:@"Answer_Box.png" target:targetedApplication selector:@selector(answerButtonTapped:)] ) {
            NSLog(@"Yes?");
            return self;
    }
    return self;

}
-(void)answerButtonTapped:(id)stuff {
    NSLog(@"Answer Button Tapped");
}
```

and it crashes every time with this error in the console

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:]: method signature argument cannot be nil'
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is -answerButtonTapped a method of targetedApplication? It should be that one. The error says that there is no such a function in target. Or you can pass "self" instead of "targetApplication"